# Как удалить последний из тегов с одинаковыми id?

Tags: jquery

На странице есть несколько тегов с одинаковым id (так получилось). Как при помощи jQuery удалить последний тег?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Нужно удалить все повторяющиеся id и оставить только первый?

Comment: @DogeDev, _"Как при помощи jquery удалить последний тег?"_

Comment: @Qwertiy Довольно странное задание - я поэтому и переспросил. Возможно, автор вопроса просто поторопился и неправильно сформулировал.

Comment: Может всё-таки лучше попытаться сделать так, чтобы так не получалось? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  $("[id='smth']").last().remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Remove</button>

<div id="smth">First</div>
<div id="smth">Second</div>
<div id="smth">Third</div>
<div id="smth">Last</div>
<div id="other">With other id</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('div#block').last().remove();`

Comment: Ненадёжно. Какие-то версии IE даже по такому селектору выдавали только первый.

Comment: @Qwertiy хотите сказать вы сделали что-то иное? Вы показали такое же решение только сделали это по нажатию на кнопку. толку тогда?

Comment: @Tsyklop не такое же, у него селектор другой

Comment: Нет, я использовал селектор по атрибуту, а у тебя тег и id.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто перебрать элементы, и если элемент последний грохнуть:

```
  <div id="test">1</div>
  <div id="test">2</div>
  <div id="test">3</div>

  <script> 
    var el_count=$('[id=test]').length;
    if(el_count>1)
      var el_index=0;
      $('[id=test]').each(function(){
          el_index++;
          if(el_index==el_count){
             $(this).remove();
          }
       }); 
     } 
   </script>
```